# What development tool to use for develop cross-platform application using Python and Qt?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt

I'm a Delphi developer I only used to develop application on Windows platform only.

From now on, I wish to develop a GUI based database applications which target Windows, Ubuntu, OSX.

I don't have much knowledge about cross platform solution, I know I little about Java, I know almost nothing about Python and Qt.

Anyway, I prefer to use Python as the programming language and use Qt for GUI, my question is I'm not quite sure about...

1. What development tool and version (prefer latest if possible) do I need to install on my development machine which is running Ubuntu 13.04?
2. What are major differences between PyQt, Qt Designer?

Answer (score 2):

Did you read basic Qt documentation?

1. You should write platform independed code to make it portable ;). Do not use OS-specific features, use Qt classes. You need a compiler for each platform. You need a Qt for each platform.
2. Visit qt-project.org and get latest versions. (And a lot of other information about Qt)
3. PyQt - is port of Qt libraries to python. Qt Designer - is software (tool) for making .ui files. Others??

Comment: Other like PySide??? I meant, I have heard lots of things but not so sure what they are.

Comment: I think I understand that Qt Designer is a tool for making a UI for my cross-platform right?  But do I need both PyQt and PySide, or just only one of them?

Comment: First, you should understand difference between next things: IDE, compiler, framework, platform. I really don't know how to explain difference between completely different things.

Comment: You should read basic documentation and ask more exact questions. I don't want to copy-paste content of qt-project wiki there.